# How to format Gmisc::htmlTable

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Below is an rmarkdown document that can be pasted into rstudio.

My problem is that output from htmlTable is prepended/appended with cruft from the htmlTable attributes.

````
---
title: "SO_question"
author: "AC"
date: "Wednesday, May 28, 2014"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: readable
---

My heading
============
This is a few tables. Notice that `htmlTable` prints `[1]"` before each table and `" attr(,“class”) [1] “htmlTable” “character” [1] “` after each table. How can I avoid this?

``` {r html_table, results='asis', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library("htmlTable")
library("reshape2")
#Chick weight example
names(ChickWeight) <- tolower(names(ChickWeight))
chick_m <- melt(ChickWeight, id=2:4, na.rm=TRUE)

for (i in unique(chick_m$diet)) {
  diet <- subset(chick_m, diet==i)
  table_to_print <- dcast(chick_m, time ~ variable, mean)
  print(htmlTable(table_to_print, rgroup=c(""), n.rgroup=nrow(table_to_print)))
}

```

Bonus question: How to format the last row in each table as bold text (suited for a 'total' row)?
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `print` on your `htmTable`, use `cat` to properly render it.

```
for (i in unique(chick_m$diet)) {
  diet <- subset(chick_m, diet==i)
  table_to_print <- dcast(chick_m, time ~ variable, mean)
  cat(htmlTable(table_to_print, rgroup=c(""), n.rgroup=nrow(table_to_print)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I remember reading a rant somewhere about "print is not cat" or something to that effect. This just goes to show. Thanks a lot, @MrFlick

Answer (score 1):

There is a `print.htmlTable` function that is called when a print is performed on an object from the `htmlTable` function. It should automatically call the `cat`, not sure if this was true May '14 but it works today.

In the 1.1 version of the **htmlTable-package** (the function was separated from the Gmisc-package) there is a total option:

```
for (i in unique(chick_m$diet)) {
  diet <- subset(chick_m, diet==i)
  table_to_print <- dcast(chick_m, time ~ variable, mean)
  print(htmlTable(table_to_print, total=TRUE))
}
```

*Note:* You do not need to specify the `rgroup` element if you are not using it.

#author

Comment: Is there a problem with the CRAN version of htmlTable?  install.packages("htmlTable") tells me it is not available for R ver. 3.2.1

Comment: Odd - not that I'm aware of and the CRAN page doesn't indicate any issue: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/htmlTable/index.html

Comment: I tried again just now, using the install packages of RStudio.  Same message.  I would really like to use the package, too.

Comment: Well, the old trick worked: close R and start over.  Then the package installed.  Sorry to bother you.  :(